# How to convert xml generated from path option to a table

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

How to get the output specified below

```
DECLARE @txml XML 
SET @txml ='<row><ch>   </ch><unicode_value>9</unicode_value><cnt>3</cnt></row><row><ch>
</ch><unicode_value>10</unicode_value><cnt>5</cnt></row><row><ch>
</ch><unicode_value>13</unicode_value><cnt>5</cnt></row><row>
<ch> </ch><unicode_value>32</unicode_value><cnt>962</cnt></row>
<row><ch>&amp;</ch><unicode_value>38</unicode_value><cnt>32</cnt></row>
'
SELECT  x.value('cnt', 'int') AS cnt,
    x.value('ch', 'nvarchar(10)') AS ch,
    x.value('unicode_value', 'int') AS unicode_value
FROM @txml.nodes('/row') AS tbl( x )
```

The output required from about should be similar like

```
cnt | ch | unicode_value|
32 | &  | 38|
8 | ( | 40|
```

etc

Comment: Problem is, your XML has really pure structure. Should be rather `<root><item><ch>  </ch><unicode_value>9</unicode_value><cnt>3</cnt></item><item><ch>
        </ch><unicode_value>10</unicode_value><cnt>5</cnt></item></root>`, to specify where one elements ends and another starts.

Comment: Thanks for that. I have changed my xml structure to '<row><ch> </ch><unicode_value>9</unicode_value><cnt>3</cnt></row><row><ch>
</ch><unicode_value>10</unicode_value><cnt>5</cnt></row><row>' Now how to get the desired result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your new XML structure you should do following:

```
SELECT  x.value('(cnt)[1]', 'int') AS cnt,
    x.value('(ch)[1]', 'nvarchar(10)') AS ch,
    x.value('(unicode_value[1])', 'int') AS unicode_value
FROM @txml.nodes('/row') AS tbl( x )
```

[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/11952)